# Simplify a Js or convert it to php)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chat

i'm trying to create a "chat" on my website, i wrote question and answer in html (radio) e hide them when not selected with js, also after the first selection the script hide the other radio and disable the selected one. Probably i should simplify the all code but i'm kind a noob with Js. There's a more simple way to achieve the same result? Should I convert it in php? Anyone can help?

Thanks a lot

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>progettodont</title>
<style type="text/css">



.classQuestion        {
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 7px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #119b97;
            display: inline-block;
            max-width: 700px;
}

.classAnswerActive   {float: right;}

.divClassAnswer {text-align: center}


.classAnswer {  margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 7px;
            color: #414042;
            background-color: #ccc;
            max-width: 700px;
            display: inline-block;
}

.classRadio     {display: none;}




</style>
</head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>




    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.classAnswer').click(function(){
        $('.classAnswer').not(this).hide();
        });
    });

    </script>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.classAnswer').on('click', function () {
            $('.classAnswer').addClass('classAnswerActive');
        });
    });

    </script>


    <div class="classQuestion">QUESTION 1_1</div>

    <div class="divClassAnswer">

    <label for="idAnswer_1_1" class="classAnswer">ANSWER 1_1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="nameAnswer_1_1" class="classRadio" 
 id="idAnswer_1_1" value="Answer_1_1">

    <label for="idAnswer_1_2" class="classAnswer">ANSWER 1_2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="nameAnswer_1_2" class="classRadio" 
 id="idAnswer_1_2" value="Answer_1_2">

 <label for="idAnswer_1_3" class="classAnswer">ANSWER 1_3</label>
 <input type="radio" name="nameAnswer_1_3" class="classRadio" 
 id="idAnswer_1_3" value="Answer_1_3">

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()   {
        $("#idAnswer_1_1").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("#idQuestion_2_1").show();
            } else {
                $("#idQuestion_2_1").hide();
            }
        });

    });

</script>


<div class="classQuestion" id="idQuestion_2_1" style="display: none">
QUESTION 2_1
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()   {
        $("#idAnswer_1_2").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("#idQuestion_2_2").show();
            } else {
                $("#idQuestion_2_2").hide();
            }
        });

    });
</script>


<div class="classQuestion" id="idQuestion_2_2" style="display: none">
        QUESTION 2_2
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()   {
        $("#idAnswer_1_3").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("#idQuestion_2_3").show();
            } else {
                $("#idQuestion_2_3").hide();
            }
        });

    });
</script>


<div class="classQuestion" id="idQuestion_2_3" style="display: none">
QUESTION 2_3
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: right, sorry, there's a more simple way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what this has to do with a 'chat' system, however you can make several improvements to your code:

- You're including multiple versions of jQuery. Only include a single one.
- Place all script within a single `<script>` in the page, and place any jQuery code in that within a single `document.ready` event handler.
- Use a common class to group the radio elements. Then you can bind a single event handler to that class. You can use a `data` attribute to store custom meta data about the element which you can then use in the event handler.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.classAnswer').click(function() {
    $('.classAnswer').not(this).hide();
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  $(".classRadio").on('change', function() {
    $('#' + $(this).data('target')).toggleClass('active', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
.classQuestion {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #119b97;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 700px;
  display: none;
}
.classQuestion.active { display: inline-block; }

.divClassAnswer {
  text-align: center
}

.classAnswer {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: #414042;
  background-color: #ccc;
  max-width: 700px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.classAnswer.active {
  float: right;
}

.classRadio {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="classQuestion active">QUESTION 1_1</div>
<div class="divClassAnswer">
  <label for="idAnswer_1_1" class="classAnswer">ANSWER 1_1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="nameAnswer_1_1" class="classRadio" id="idAnswer_1_1" value="Answer_1_1" data-target="idQuestion_2_1">

  <label for="idAnswer_1_2" class="classAnswer">ANSWER 1_2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="nameAnswer_1_2" class="classRadio" id="idAnswer_1_2" value="Answer_1_2" data-target="idQuestion_2_2">

  <label for="idAnswer_1_3" class="classAnswer">ANSWER 1_3</label>
  <input type="radio" name="nameAnswer_1_3" class="classRadio" id="idAnswer_1_3" value="Answer_1_3" data-target="idQuestion_2_3">
</div>

<div class="classQuestion" id="idQuestion_2_1">QUESTION 2_1</div>
<div class="classQuestion" id="idQuestion_2_2">QUESTION 2_2</div>
<div class="classQuestion" id="idQuestion_2_3">QUESTION 2_3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...a "chat", as i called it, it's more an exchange of information between me and my guest. I've to write a lot of questions and answer, obiouvsly the code i showed it's a minimal part of the entire code. I called it chat because i want to style it like a kind of Whatsapp conversation.